# Hadoop Single node cluster HDFS recovery

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have Hadoop 1.2.1 running on my machine in single-node-cluster mode.
It was running a task with 0 reduce tasks.

The output of each map task was clearly being written on the HDFS as part-000**

But then the system on which the hadoop system was running crashed. Now i want to `copyToLocal` the output of the Map tasks that completed successfully.

I can see all the "parts" listed when i do `hadoop dfs -ls /output_dir`, however `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /output_dir LOCAL_PATH` fails with the following error :

> copyToLocal: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException:
>   Zero  blocklocations for ... . Name node is in safe mode.

I am not able to start my data node, most solutions that i found involved formatting the namenode using `hadoop namenode -format`. I do not want to loose the data.

Can the output be recovered from the dfs.tmp.dir ?

Comment: Why aren't you able to start your datanode?

Comment: `ERROR datanode.DataNode: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.`

Comment: Hmm yeah that's no good.  You might be able find the blocks for your map output in the dfs.data.dir.  You'll have to put them back together yourself though.

Comment: Hmm, ya that's what i figured too. Was looking for a possiblity of restoring the HDFS. 
Thanks @climbage!